# Convert datetime stored as char the YYYMMDDHHmmSS format to datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

I'm working with a table where the date and time of an event is stored as a char in the format YYYMMDDHHmmSS or '20120606122012'. I need to compare this to the current timestamp to see if it's been more than 20 minutes since the event happened, but that seems to be more difficult than I anticipated.

Is it possible to do this, or if not: is there a different approach that works?

Comment: The best approach would be to use a more appropriate datatype such as `datetime`. Is that an option?

Comment: First convert your string to `datetime` and then you can use `datediff` to check the difference between the time of the event and the current timestamp.  But the best would be to follow @MartinSmith 's advice.

Comment: I agree that would be the best way to do it, but unfortunately the guy who designed this wasn't in the habit of doing things the best way.

We're working on cleaning up the data model, but this needs to be done before we can finish that work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do some string manipulation to get your string to the format `YYYYMMDD HH:mm:SS` and you can cast/convert to `datetime`.

Something like this:

```
declare @S varchar(50)
set @S = '20120606122012'

select cast(left(@S, 8)+' '+substring(@S, 9, 2)+':'+substring(@S, 11, 2)+':'+substring(@S, 13, 2) as datetime)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also add this as a computed column or make it part of a view, so that you don't have to perform the calculation over and over in every query.

As a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD dt
AS CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(col,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'), 120);
```

Since the calculation is deterministic, it can be persisted and/or indexed.

Using a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view_whatever
AS
    SELECT /* other columns, */
      dt = CONVERT(DATETIME, STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(col,9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':'))
    FROM dbo.whatever;
```

Then you can simply say:

```
WHERE dt < DATEADD(MINUTE, -20, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Though I have to agree with the others - you need to fix the model. There is no advantage whatsoever to storing this as a string, except that your users don't get pesky error messages when they enter non-date junk like `whosawatsa` or even `20120230000000`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, will correct. Certain I was able to add an index without the style parameter but also know that I've had to do it that way in the past